# Manage Attributes: color option

Tags: magento

I added a color attribute under custom options for a product. I tried to enable that option through the "manage Attributes" menu by clicking on color option, but it returned an error as given below:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in
>   /home/rnrn1004/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tabs.php
>   on line 50

Comment: magento version? what's the code around line 50 in  `/home/rnrn1004/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tabs.php`? does it work when you disable all extensions?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.7.0.2... I am not even able to create a new attribute set. Sounds weird...

Comment: Sounds like something was corrupted in your database.  What error do you receive when you attempt to create a new attribute set?  If this is a new site setup, I would recommend reinstalling Magento which would be the fastest approach in solving the corrupted data.

Comment: It doesn't display anything when I try to add a new set. Was thinking of re-installation as a last option. Still trying to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally! I recently restored website files from the backup, and a file has been missing since the restore. Bringing that file in solved the problem.